# Infinispan/hibernate 2nd level cache update not transactional?

Tags: hibernate, jboss, transactions, infinispan, second-level-cache

Infinispan as hibernate 2nd level cache isn't updating in a transactional manner similar to how a database transaction works.  By this I mean, a database transaction is not visible to other transactions until completely committed.  Based on logging, I've observed transactions (JEE MDB) being able to partial updates of a given Infinispan update.  To elaborate, here's my setup:

1. Jboss
2. JPA (hibernate)
3. Infinispan as the 2nd level cache provider (local cache transaction mode FULL_XA.
4. JTA is enabled.
5. Database is setup as a XA datasource

What I appear to have seen is that if a JEE bean is started post the DB commit of a transaction and what I believe to be the infinispan update (commit), it can see some of the infinispan update (which isn't how a database transaction work and is undesirable.)   Please help.

Also, please confirm that 
1) Second level cache only gets updated on transaction commit.
2) I'm not totally crazy in thinking that the update should be atomic to other transactions... either they see none of it or all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Might sound crazy, but what you ask is very expensive to do for a cache :)

I originally started with such design back 10 years, where Infinispan could act as an XA resource with Hibernate. It was dog slow.

Clearly that was not the right solution, so we moved to integrate with Hibernate via a Synchronization which was big improvement. At this point Infinispan was still transactional and would have behaved the way you see.

Transactional Infinispan was eventually removed, again for performance reasons, once we figured out how to deal with clustered situations without transactions.

The key thing for Hibernate 2LC is that it should help speed up your applications. Consistency is important of course, so we make sure that any rollbacks are reflected in Infinispan, but yeah, halfway through the transaction data might already be in the cache.

If in-flight data consistency is an issue somehow, I'd recommend using optimistic locking, which Infinispan cache provider can take advantage of to compare data versions. So it can see whether an older data version is trying update a newer one, but we've not seen such cases since a lot of such situations are forbidden by Hibernate itself.

As always, if you have a specific situation that's causing trouble do let us know.

p.s. We have created several Hibernate Infinispan simple tutorials for different environemnts (local, spring, wildfly) [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/tree/main/integrations/hibernate), so I'd suggest you look at those. Not only do they have code examples, but they have configuration set ups that work nicely :).

p.s.2. Those examples do not set FULL_XA on the cache ;)

Comment: The link is no longer working but I think the tutorials can now be found [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/tree/main/integrations/hibernate)

Comment: Thx Felix, I've updated the link in the response.